# How to Execute a Formula Composed of Strings? Indirect Not Working

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

As an example to illustrate my point, I want to take an average of the range A1:A25, but I want to be able to specify this range outside of the formula.

Normally, the formula would be:

```
=AVERAGE(A1:A25)
```

But in order to achieve what i'm looking for, i'm trying:

```
=INDIRECT(AVERAGE(B1))
```

Where B1 contains the string: A1:A25

But this just gives a '#NAME?' error.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: maybe `=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(B1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your nesting the wrong way around. Try

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(B1))
```

Comment: And if B1 was on another sheet, for example:

Sheet1!B1  - just AVERAGE(INDIRECT(Sheet1!B1)) - how to separate the B1 from the sheet? Concatenate?